# elastic search: special cases for empty value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have filtered query who has filter by type:

But when I not set type directly, it return me all values, even which have some type setted.

How could I build the query, which will me return only values with `type=[]` if I do not specify type in the query?

Comment: Have you tried the [missing filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-missing-filter.html#query-dsl-missing-filter)?